# multiplication two columns in data grid wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a three columns
productname - mount - price
I need to show a fourth column when I insert mount and price , the fourth column 
is mount  multiplication price as an example
productname - mount - price - Total,
Total= mount* Price

Comment: please post whatever you have come up with so far in order for others to help you suitably. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In your model class add another property called as Total and where you assign the other property's there assign the total value, now you can bind the Total property in your total column of data grid.

```
ex: 
productname = aaa
mount = 1
price = 10
Total= mount * Price
```